# How to pass an image to a TypeScript React component

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap

I have written a React component in TypeScript like this:

```
const SingleColumn = (image: any, heading: string, para: string) => {return(
  <Col className="col-md-4 my-4">
    <img src={image} alt="" className="w-100"/>
    <h4 className="my-4">{heading}</h4>
    <p>{para}</p>
    <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-md">Our Story</a>
  </Col>
)};
```

And I am calling this component in my code like this:

```
import img from '../img/1.jpg';
<Row className="row my-5">
  <SingleColumn image={img1} heading="Amazing.Incredible." para="Use the adjective amazing"/>
</Row>
```

I have two problems with this code.

1. The type of the image parameter is `any`. What should be the right type? How do you find the right type of an HTML element? Is there a way to query it?
2. I am getting a compilation error saying `Tag 'SingleColumn' expects at least '3' arguments, but the JSX factory 'React.createElement' provides at most '2'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the context it's being used in the code, the type of image should be a string.

   ```js
   <img src={<string>} />
   ```

   Here it is explained in details: *[<img>: The Image Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)*
2. You shouldn't pass properties to a component like that. All the properties should be in one object under one object, usually called "props" like so:

   ```js
   const SingleColumn = (props: {
     image: string;
     heading: string;
     para: string;
   }) => (
     <div className="col-md-4 my-4">
       <Col className="col-md-4 my-4">
         <img src={image} alt="" className="w-100" />
         <h4 className="my-4">{heading}</h4>
         <p>{para}</p>
         <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-md">
           Our Story
         </a>
       </Col>
     </div>
   );
   ```

   Or you can do destructuring like

   ```js
   const SingleColumn = ({ image, heading, para }) => (
     <div className="col-md-4 my-4">
       <Col className="col-md-4 my-4">
         <img src={image} alt="" className="w-100" />
   ...
   ```

I would highly recommend you to make interfaces like

```js
interface ISingleColumnProps {
  image: any;
  heading: string;
  para: string;
}

const SingleColumn = (props: ISingleColumnProps) => (
...
```

*[Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)* is a great example of how React passes props.

- EDIT

Another options is by using React.FC Like the following

```js
interface ISingleColumnProps {
  image: string;
  heading: string;
  para: string;
}
const SingleColumn: React.FC<ISingleColumnProps> = ({image, heading, para}) => (
  <div className="col-md-4 my-4">
    <Col className="col-md-4 my-4">
      <img src={image} alt="" className="w-100" />
      <h4 className="my-4">{heading}</h4>
      <p>{para}</p>
      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-md">
        Our Story
      </a>
    </Col>
  </div>
);
```